# Breaking for loop from fs.readdir function in javascript for discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have been searching many websites and articles but there are no good explanation on how to do it

```
fs.readdir(`./commands`, (err, folders) => {
  let loop = true;
  for (const folder of folders) {
    fs.readdir(`./commands/${folder}`, (err, files) => {
      if (files.includes(`${command.infos.name}.js`)) {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve(`../${folder}/${command.infos.name}.js`)];
        client.commands.delete(commandName);
        try {
          const newCommand = require(`../${folder}/${command.infos.name}.js`);
          message.client.commands.set(newCommand.infos.name, newCommand);
          message.channel.send(`Command \`${newCommand.infos.name}\` was reloaded!`);
          return false;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return message.channel.send(`There was an error while reloading a command \`${command.infos.name}\`:\n\`${error.message}\``);
        }
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
    if (result === false) {
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to break the for loop when the `` if (files.includes(`${command.infos.name}.js`)) `` is true so that the program won't continue to check other folder if it already find the file that it wants to reload.

I want to use `fs.readdir` because it's an asynchronous function but since it's an asynchronous function I can't change any value from the outside of the `fs.readdir`. I have tried using promise but I can't seem to understand it. So I'm hoping if there is other method to break the `for` loop without removing the asynchronous part of the code.

Comment: You can't break the loop from there.  And, it's even worse because your `fs.readdir()` operations are all running in parallel, so all the other ones have already been started by the time you even want to break the loop.  If you want to sequence the operations in your loop, then you will want to use `await fs.promises.readdir()` instead of the way you have it structured now.

Comment: Ok, I will try it.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to use ```fs.promises.readdir()``` on my code?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer and this is the answer

```
fs.readdir(`./commands`, async(err, folders) => {
  for (const folder of folders) {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(`./commands/${folder}`);
    if (files.includes(`${command.infos.name}.js`)) {
      delete require.cache[require.resolve(`../${folder}/${command.infos.name}.js`)];
      client.commands.delete(commandName);
      try {
        const newCommand = require(`../${folder}/${command.infos.name}.js`);
        message.client.commands.set(newCommand.infos.name, newCommand);
        message.channel.send(`Command \`${newCommand.infos.name}\` was reloaded!`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.channel.send(`There was an error while reloading a command \`${command.infos.name}\`:\n\`${error.message}\``);
      }
      break;
    } 
  }
});
```